# Calculate hue rotation in fabric js

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

How to we calculate rotation parameter value(-1 to 1) in Hue Rotation Filter in fabricjs from normal hue degree value(0-360)?

How does fabricjs calculate the rotation value in the Hue Rotation filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation is from -180 to 180, just for simmetry with other filters like contrast and brightness that move from -1 to 1.

When fabricjs calculate the rotation multiply the value of rotation for `Math.PI` so it moves from -1 radian to 1 radian, making a full rotation of 2 radians that equal to 360 degree.

Since the hue rotation matrix is built just with sin and cos that are periodic function of the angle in radians, you do not have to worry about the limit.
If you want to set rotation to 2 is fine, you will get the same result as 0. rotation of 3 will give the result of and so on.

```
calculateMatrix: function() {
  var rad = this.rotation * Math.PI, cos = Math.cos(rad), sin = Math.sin(rad),
      aThird = 1 / 3, aThirdSqtSin = Math.sqrt(aThird) * sin, OneMinusCos = 1 - cos;
  this.matrix = [
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
  ];
  this.matrix[0] = cos + OneMinusCos / 3;
  this.matrix[1] = aThird * OneMinusCos - aThirdSqtSin;
  this.matrix[2] = aThird * OneMinusCos + aThirdSqtSin;
  this.matrix[5] = aThird * OneMinusCos + aThirdSqtSin;
  this.matrix[6] = cos + aThird * OneMinusCos;
  this.matrix[7] = aThird * OneMinusCos - aThirdSqtSin;
  this.matrix[10] = aThird * OneMinusCos - aThirdSqtSin;
  this.matrix[11] = aThird * OneMinusCos + aThirdSqtSin;
  this.matrix[12] = cos + aThird * OneMinusCos;
},
```

so

```
filter.rotation = angleInDegree / Math.PI
```

Should work

Comment: Is there any way to get the current hex/hsl[ especially H value] values for the object and then change the rotation with respect to the current one to some pre-calculated H value ?

Comment: what object? the image can have all hue values, if you change them all to a predefined H you get a monocrome image.

Comment: ok.. i get that now. Actually i need to change the color of a product(solid color) on some predefined color swatches ..

Comment: open a question with an example, is harder to understand like this. The TSHIRT color changing question was your?

Comment: yes .. that was my question .. i need to do the same for every color . there will be single object in the canvas i.e the tshirt image.. on clicking the color buttons i need to change the color of the image .. can you give me some possible solution?